# Is it possible to preload a nested object into an ActiveRecord relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to parse a snapshot of an object, which is stored in a Postgres database in a jsonb column, into an object of the snapshotted model.
The json is multi-leveled, meaning that it has the fields of the object AND the fields of all child objects. The result I'm trying to achieve is similar to the way models can automatically populate nested objects with the usage of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but with SQL.

One major problem is that the method that tries to get the snapshots needs to return an ActiveRecord_Relation object, so I have to do this on the ORM level and I can't just retrieve the json, parse it and stick it together however I want.

I know that I can retrieve the top-level fields and make ActiveRecord present them as objects of the right class by using a subquery:

```
def self.snapshots_sql
  sql = 'SELECT '
  sql << self.columns_hash { |name, props| "(snapshot_data->>'#{name}')::#{props.sql_type} AS #{name}" }.join(', ')
  sql << ' FROM snapshots'
  sql
end

def self.get_snapshots
  self.from("(#{snapshots_sql}) AS #{self.table_name}")
end
```

which produces a query like such:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    (snapshot_data->>'id')::bigint AS id,
    (snapshot_data->>'name')::text AS name,
    ...other columns...
  FROM snapshots
) AS table_name
```

but I'm not sure if it's possible to also query for the nested objects.

I've tried adding statements such as the following to the select in the subquery:

`(snapshot_data->>child_data->>'name') as "child_table.name"`

`(snapshot_data->>child_data->>'name') as "child_tables.name"`

`(snapshot_data->>child_data->>'name') as "child_table_attributes.name"`

as well as using a `joins` method on the query: `self.joins(:child_table).from("(#{snapshots_sql}) AS #{self.table_name}")` but `ParentModel.get_snapshots.first.child_table` always returns `nil`.

Is there a way to do this on the ORM level?

Comment: rather than `joins` you can use `includes` (1 or 2 queries) or `eager_load` (1 query)

Comment: I've read about those and it seems they can only preload the actual records from the database. What I want to do is to return a snapshot of that record, which is stored in a jsonb column and make ActiveRecord treat it as the actual records.

Comment: In that case I would recommend looking at the `ActiveModel` library (which is basically how AR objects are created) or the `ActiveRecord::composed_of` method. These will allow you to load the `Snapshot` into a real class. Implementation of persistence concerns would still be your responsibility but not that difficult to implement.